# Align multiple views vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've to make something that looks like these:

[image]

---

[image]

I have a `NSArray` of `walking` and `car` objects. 
`Car` class has a `NSString` property which contains these numbers.

How can I do this ? Thanks.

Comment: If you already have an NSArray of these elements, what have you tried till now? Sounds like your not completely new to iOS

Answer (score 0):

You could create UIImageViews and UILabels programatically and line them up in a cell/view whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `UIView` as a container, with an `UIImageView` on the left and a `UITextView` on the right. This would be the template for the **car** object. Your **walking** object would just need a simple `UIImageView`. Then calculate the point you want the first `UIImage` to start at and add the next container at the end of the previous element. you could also create a template of your arrow, this way you just would need to connect the elements like you want. It should look like this

```
CGFloat fHeightImage = 20.0f;

UIView *view = 
 [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                          [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                                          fHeightImage)];
UIImageView *imageViewCar = 
 [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                               fHeightImage,
                                               fHeightImage)];
[imageViewCar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"walking"]];
[view addSubview:imageViewCar];
UIImageView *imageViewArrow = 
 [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(imageViewCar.frame),
                                               CGRectGetHeight(imageViewCar.frame),
                                               fHeightImage,
                                               fHeightImage)];
[imageViewArrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"]];
[view addSubview:imageViewArrow];
```